# How can my bot give a user a role through a command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

For example, I want that if I enter !Cuff @user that this user gets the role of cuff. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
if message.content.startswith('!cuff'):
    args = message.content.split(' ')
    if len(args) == 2:
        member: Member = discord.utils.find(lambda m: args[1] in m.name, message.guild.members)
        if member:
            role = get(message.server.roles, name='Cuff')
            await client.add_roles('{}'.format(member.name))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can edit your post to insert your code there.

Comment: Can you edit your post with your code?

Comment: No, it is always written so distorted

Comment: I meant your question. There's a `Edit` button under your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a command, you should use [`discord.ext.commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands) instead of `on_message` event. Then, you can get the `discord.Member` object easily with passing arguments.

Also, `client` object has no attribute `add_roles`. You should use [`discord.Member.add_roles(role)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles) and `message` object has no attribute `server`, it has `guild` instead.

```py
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@client.command()
async def cuff(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
    if not member:
        return # or you can send message to the channel that says "you have to pass member argument"
    role = get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Cuff')
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'discord.message' has no attribute 'guild'

Comment: What version of discord.py are you using?

Comment: Python  version 3.7.4

Comment: I meant do you use `repl.it` or `rewrite` version of discord.py. If rewrite, then what version of rewrite (1.4.x, 1.5.x etc.) do you use?

Comment: I think it should be `ctx.guild.roles`, `message` is not defined

Comment: Right, I've missed that. I edited the answer, you can check the new answer.

Comment: discord.py 1.6.0

Comment: Did new answer fixed your problem?